# Thermometric Properties

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, temperature, electrical-resistance, voltage

> A thermocouple thermometer with 10 ohms of resistance is calibrated with its hot junction and cold junction immersed in steam and melting ice respectively. An EMF of 5.6mv is measured.
>
> This thermocouple is then used in series with a voltmeter of resistance 100 ohm. If the voltmeter recorded 2.8 mV when the cold junction is in melting ice and its hot junction is in a liquid bath, what is the temperature of the liquid bath on the Centigrade scale?

I understand the calculations involved in finding the answer.  However, I am unsure of how either of the resistances affect the calculations.  Why are the resistances important?

Answer (score 1):

An ideal voltmeter has infinite resistance and will not allow current to flow through its leads. In this case the voltmeter has a rather low resistance (I would throw out such a voltmeter)

Below are two circuit diagrams, the first shows an ideal thermocouple and an ideal voltmeter. The second shows a more realistic version of each with the included resistance values. For the thermocouple, the ideal allows current to flow freely, so the resistor is added in series. For the voltmeter, the ideal allows no current to flow, so the resistor is added in parallel to allow flow.

[image]

Comment: If you need further explanation, I'll add how to solve.